# Provide an example of $X$ and $ A$ where $\inf_{y\in A} \Vert x-y \Vert <1$ for every $x \in X $ with $\Vert x \Vert =1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an inner product space, and $A$ a closed subspace of $X$ with $A\neq X$.

Provide an example of $X$ and $ A$ where $\inf_{y\in A} \Vert x-y \Vert <1$ for every $x \in X $ with $\Vert x \Vert =1$

My attempt:

I try to start with $A=\{ f\in C[0,1]: \int_{0}^{1}fg=0\}$, but I am stuck here, I don't know how to use the incompleteness.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $A=X$, then $\inf=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, I edited $A \neq X$

Comment: Then take as $A$ orthogonal complement to some discontinuous function $f$ in $L^2([0,1])$ intersected with $C([0,1])$. We can normalize to have $\|f\|=1$. Since $\pm f$ is not in $C([0,1])$ anything there with $\|x\|=1$ will be at a distance $<1$ from $A$ by the Pythagorean theorem. This requires your inner product space to be incomplete. If it is complete this is impossible.

Comment: Ries’s Lemma provides a construction of the object you are seeking for a general Banach space. Also, notice that if Y is closed, then the infimum is the generalization of orthogonality for Banach spaces.

Comment: @gdepaul I don't see how [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) produces an answer to this question

Comment: Following up Conifold's comment: a convenient $f$ to work with would be a step-function such as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < \frac 12\\
1 & x \geq \frac 12
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion in the comments.  Take $X = C[0,1]$ with the $\int fg$ inner-product. One example of such a space $A$ would be
$$
A = \left\{f \in C[0,1]:\int_0^{1/2}f(x)\,dx = 0\right\}.
$$